# What's the story behind VW Dubium?

Tags: vw

What is the story behind **Volkswagen Dubium** merch? There is a lot of T-shirts and hoodies whit styled to periodic table element **Vw** with number **49** or **105** and word **dubium** ([check out google](https://www.google.com/search?q=vw%20dubium)), but I can find no explanation what does it mean

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't about Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair as spelled out in the [Help Center](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Surely it's an advertising gimmick: "Vw" looks like a periodic table symbol for an element, and "Dubium" looks and sounds like the name of a chemical element. And I agree this is off-topic here.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 actually I got no better place than SE, thats why question is here. I saw that merch in VW parts store, just cannot go to than store again. So it's still quite related to cars, but rules is a rules. Maybe I should go to reddit

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica in that case, what is the numbers means? There is variety of other element-name-like words, why Dubium? There is definitely some hidden meaning

Comment: "Dub" as in "VDub." Maybe the numbers have no meaning. A mystery.

Comment: [Maybe this will help you understand.](https://www.logotypes101.com/logos/132/28391FE23AA512C27A5B9AE86DD7E287/breakingbad.png) It's a picture of the logo for Breaking Bad (tv series). They used them like what's on the periodic table of elements. The number denotes the atomic weight of the atom. I saw it as either 49 or 105, depending on which style you look at, but both 49 and 105 are taken on the periodic table, so sort of stupid to a degree. And as David said, the name is made up to sound like an element: v"Dub"ium. No hidden meaning. Just trying to look smart and failing (IMHO).

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I finally got, that w is double v, so all that makes sense. Although I think we can dig deeper

Comment: 49th element in Indium, which I cannot relate to VW at all, but 105th is 105 is Dubnium, which is almost like dubium
As soon as english is not my native lang Im afraid I will not be able to understand the witty
anyway, thank you guys!

Comment: @BankAngle - You're thinking too hard about it. Don't read into what isn't there. Remember [Occam's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor).

Comment: The current legal incarnation of VW was founded in 1949, when the British occupation forces handed back control to the German government. VW certainly existed prior to that date, but they don't like to talk about it.